# ASP.NET vs Intraweb

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Como venho do PHP e estou começando agora com ASP.NET e estou bem cru, vou precisar argumentar sobre .NET para um dos donos da empresa, e ele desenvolve em IntraWEB. Pela minha visão de WEB, a estrutura do .NET é bem melhor de se trabalhar, tanto na parte estrutural como conceitual.

Até essa parte ok, o problema é quando entra a programação "expandida" que eles já tem aqui, por exemplo: No IntraWEB, ele tem um componente "menu" que vem de uma DLL desenvolvida por ele, ele inclui essa DLL no projeto, solta esse menu no na aplicação e o menu já está funcionando, e caso ele precise mudar algo ou até consertar um *bug*, ele vai até usa DLL, compila e já está tudo certo em todos os menus das aplicações daquele menu estendido. Eles não querem migrar justamente por isso, dizem que no .NET não tem esse tipo de coisa.

Aaah, entre outros argumentos como "recuperação" de formulário, porque o formulário no Intraweb são objetos, você pode trazer esse objeto na tela a hora que quiser e com todos os dados digitados pelo usuário, até que você "destrua" o mesmo...

Consigo fazer isso no .NET?

Comment: Diego, Intraweb não é aquele framework que é disponibilizado pelo Delphi? Se eles já têm uma DLL, porque você não tenta abrir um projeto asp.net mvc ou mesmo webform, e faz uma tentativa de leitura da dll pelo "Add Reference" do visual studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Claro que pode fazer isso. Em ASP.NET clássico tem as [Master Pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.140)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Em ASP.NET MVC, que é bem melhor, tem os [*layouts* ou *sections*](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/721055/ASP-NET-MVC-Layout-and-Section-in-Razor) ou ainda pode criar seus próprios componentes com [*tags* HTML personalizadas](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), pelo menos nas versões mais novas.

Especialmente quando falamos de ASP.NET MVC estamos falando de algo moderno, que aprendeu com os erros de coisas mais antigas, que possuem formas melhores de fazer várias coisas. Certamente será diferente. Haverá resistência em mudar. Muitas vezes falarão que é ruim porque ainda não sabem usar. A pessoa prefere fazer pior no que ela sabe.

Mas minha recomendação é aprender a tecnologia profundamente não só antes de usá-la, mas até mesmo antes de vendê-la. A regra número 1 de todo vendedor é conhecer o produto que está vendendo. Você não vai convencer ninguém usar algo que nem você sabe se é bom ou não.

Quando você conhecer bem, qualquer oposição que ele faça, você terá uma boa resposta.

[Tutorial básico](http://www.asp.net/mvc?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Comment: Exatamente! Venho do PHP e usei Framework CakePHP, que é bem parecido com o ASP.NET MVC. Tenho uma noção bem básica em vista do que a ferramenta pode proporcionar. 
Acabei de falar com os desenvolvedores aqui e já ajeitamos esse esquema de "gerar" componentes via DLL externa.
Acho que o único ponto que vou me "ferrar", vai ser esses esquema de form guardado em memória (que é horrível pelo consumo de memória), mas vou ter que estudar isso.
Quanto ao conhecimento da ferramenta, super concordo com você.
Obrigado mesmo, cara! Valeu!